# Using the meta keyword HTML tag to improve search engine results?

Tags: discussion, design, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't Stack Exchange sites use HTML <meta> tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80491/why-dont-stack-exchange-sites-use-html-meta-tags)

While scanning the HTML of a page on Arqade I noticed the `meta` tag is not being used for keywords.

As far as I understand things search engines can use these meta keywords to further evaluate the relevancy of a page's contents for a given topic.

Would it make sense, then, to use the tags in a question as meta keywords for a given page? So if I have a question on stackoverflow with the `c++` and `compiler` tags, one might see the following in the HTML:

```
<meta name='keywords' content='c++,compiler'>
```

Would such a change improve search engine relevancy for SE content?

Comment: I _think_ Google has been ignoring keywords for almost a decade now...

Comment: related: [Why don't Stack Exchange sites use HTML <meta> tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80491/why-dont-stack-exchange-sites-use-html-meta-tags)

Comment: @YannisRizos According to http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html you'd be correct.

Comment: Also: Here's a list of the meta tags Google does pay attention to: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meta keywords tag has zero effect on search engine rankings. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow often has questions being indexed and showing up in Google searches within *minutes*.

I think that says it all. They aren't important. (though I wish I could convince some of my clients of that, who insist on "keywords" on pages...)

Quite likely one of the biggest problems with 'keywords' is that they were very artificial; they did not at all represent the *actual content* on the page, which is much more useful for indexing.